# Is there a equivalent of SpringBatch in the Java EE world?

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-batch, java-ee-7

I like the features of SpringBatch however, I do most of my development in the Java EE space. Is there any part of the current Java EE 7 spec that addresses batch processing?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/batch-processing.htm#GKJIQ6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSR-352 which is based on Spring Batch is part of the EE specification.  That being said, Spring Batch does support JSR-352 so you can use Spring Batch as your JSR-352 implementation if you'd like.  As an example there's a good blog post about how to do that with wildfly here: http://www.radcortez.com/spring-batch-as-wildfly-module/